# In four probe experiment why the graph looks like in low temperature

Tags: experimental-physics, solid-state-physics, electronics, experimental-technique

I found a graph between the log of resistivity vs inverse of temperature like this

[image: graph between log ro vs temp inverse]

So in region 2, why is the graph going down?

Comment: Not enough  information given, to answer. Please give the origin and a scale to your graph, maybe the metal melts?

Comment: @Trula The dip is at the low temperature end.

Comment: It may be an indication of the onset of the superconducting state.

Comment: @trula I dont think this is a metal

Comment: "I found": where? This graph by itself is hard to interpret, but the original source might describe it better.

Comment: Since there are no data points at lower temperatures, this is a (poor) bit of artistic license. Think of it as a bad spline fit (or even good ones can do weird things). Ignore it unless there is a good explanation in text accompanying this graph.

Comment: [Source](https://iitr.ac.in/Academics/static/Department/Physics/BTech%201st%20year%20lab/Four-probe.pdf) found using Google Images.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the link provided by Farcher, the explanation is provided :

Explanation of Graph-2
The resistivity of a Germanium crystal as a function of inverse temperature. For this sample when
T < T’ 0K i.e. region (2), conduction is mainly due to the impurity carriers ( extrinsic region ). For T >
T’ 0K conduction is due to electrons transferred to the conduction band and the corresponding holes
created in the valence band (this is the intrinsic region).